# How to initialize a custom UITableViewCell from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I would like to know how to get an instance of my custom UITableViewCell so that I can set a UITextfield as the first responder

This is how I set the custom cell inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomFinishingCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

however when I try to set an instance of the selected cell inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath I get an error

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomFinishingCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // error
    [cell.widthTexField becomeFirstResponder];
```

This is the error I receive

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CustomFinishingCell *' with an expression of type 'UITableViewCell *'

Comment: compiler error, or runtime error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to cast the `UITableViewCell` returned by `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to your subclass

```
CustomFinishingCell *cell = (CustomFinishingCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // error
```

Additionally, I don't know if you just omitted this from the code you've posted, but as is you never actually declared the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
CustomFinishingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: regarding your second line of code, I thought this line of code **cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];** was in essance doing the same thing... could you elaborate on that? just i have been having issues when i go to select the nextUITableViewCell outside of the view its not instantiating itself.. so am getting errors I just dont kow why.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a cast:

```
CustomFinishingCell *cell = (CustomFinishingCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You should see a warning in this line saying that there is a problem in the affectation.

Answer (score 0):

1. `initWithStyle` is `UITableViewCell`'s initialize method , did you override it and return `CustomFinishingCell`?
2. Adding a cast

   ```
   CustomFinishingCell *cell = (CustomFinishingCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   ```